# How to improve multithread performance in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

Here is the main part of my code, to speed it up I am using multithread which is showing below, so my basic idea is to simply chunk them into 12 parts and let's them do their job separately

```
    int Thread_num=12;
    int firstone=0;
    int lastone=vector.size();
    int chunk = (lastone-firstone+(Thread_num-1))/Thread_num;
    std::thread t[Thread_num];       
   for(int i=0;i<Thread_num;i++)
{
  int s =firstone+i*chunk;
  int e = ((s+chunk)<vector.size())? (s+chunk) : vector.size();

  t[i]=std::thread(calculateAll,data,arr,s,e);         
}
for (int i = 0; i < Thread_num; ++i)
{
  t[i].join();
}
```

and here is the calculateAll function (not exact code), and I use lock to lock push_back part to avoid they write into that `list` vector at the same time( the order does not matter).

```
void calculateAll(int ***data,LineIndex* arr,int s,int e)
{
  for(int a=s;a<e;a++)
  {
    function_1(arr) /*do something with array(arr)*/
    result=function_2(data) /*do something with data*/
    mylock.lock();
    list.push_back(result);       
    mylock.unlock();
  }
}
```

So theoretically，will that be speeded up 12 times? when I use that idea in my code, it speed up like 5 to 6 times, does this make sense? and can I modify something to make the performance better, maybe use some other method? Appreciated

Comment: Do you really have 12+ cores on your machine?

Comment: I run it on server which has 14 core total, and 12 threads is the best performance I can get

Comment: Also read up on [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law), given that it seems likely that the [embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) part of your code isn't the entire workload.

Comment: according to your code, your threads should probably receive a "list" to store their results (one list per thread) and after they are done you should merge them into a final "list", this would avoid the need for the locks and could improve the performance.

Comment: @JoãoAugusto, I have try to use future to catch return value from each thread like you said, and the function I use is that 'std::async(std::launch::async, calculateAll, data, arr, s, e)', but it does not perform good even more slow, that is why I use a global vector 'list' to store them all, and true it will improve performance if I find some way to solve that problem, but the problem is show can I catch each thread result 'list' maybe I used that 'future' in the wrong way..any idea?

Comment: The thing stopping your program from bigger performance (I don't think 12x, but higher than 5x) is the lock. If you're sure there is no problem with several processes writing into the list, you can remove the lock and speed it up

Comment: @fernando.reyes The order in the 'list' vector does not matter, so like I do not care which thread write in the 'list' first. But the problem is if I do not use lock there is gonna be a error 'Aborted (core dumped)', do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @MMzztx I think Peter Becker already answered that part. If you create a list for each process to return their results and consolidate all at the end, it should be totally parallel with exception of the consolidation.

Comment: @MMzztx: Why don't you just use something like: list l[Thread_num] and pass the l[i] as a parameter to the thread function and in the end after all threads are done you just copy data from l[1..n] to l[0] ?

Comment: @JoãoAugusto I get your point! thank you so much, I am going to try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `lock()` and `unlock()` are killing performance, turning your parallel algorithm into a more-or-less serial one. As one of the comments suggests, give each thread its own list to store its results in, and when all the threads have finished, consolidate the results.

On a different tack, when you say your server has 14 cores, is that actual, physical cores, or is it 7 cores, each with two hyper-threads? If it's the latter, the hyper-threads interfere with each other, and you don't get the full speedup that you'd get from separate cores.

Comment: Someone told me to use like 'auto fut=std::async(std::launch::async, calculateAll, data, arr, s, e)' to catch the result rather than 't[i]=std::thread(calculateAll,data,arr,s,e);' in my code, but it seems perfom so slow, it seems like no threads... any idea

Comment: @MMzztx - ask that as a new question.